# How to copy a file in a upstart script on Linux?

Tags: linux, upstart

I have a simple upstart job. I want to copy a file there when it is restarted. I can not get it to work. I have read how to execute bash scripts etc from upstart but I dont get it to work. This is what I have tried:

```
script
    exec bash -c 'cp /opt/test/test.log /opt/test/test.log.old'
end script
```

When I stop and start the service the file is not copied. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be run within the `pre-start script` tag:

```
pre-start script
    exec bash -c 'cp /opt/test/test.log /opt/test/test.log.old'
end script
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an Upstart job:

Create /etc/init/myjob.conf

> vi /etc/init/myjob.conf

with content like the following:

> description     "my job"
>
> start on startup
>
> task
>
> exec /path/to/my/script.sh

Your script.sh file contains:

> cp /opt/test/test.log /opt/test/test.log.old